# How to Add Suffix to range of cells with existing Data

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

**Input:**

```
55958   55959       
55960   55961   55962   55963
60346   60347       
60348   60349
```

**Output:**

```
55958-K 55959-K     
55960-K 55961-K 55962-K 55963-K
60346-K 60347-K     
60348-K 60349-K
```

I want to Add suffix "-K" with all Range of cells.

First I tried with Custom Number Format   { "#-K" }

This is only works with formats, So i skipped it (Because i need with value).

Then I Try one formula 
`=IF(A1="","",A1&"-K")` But here I need to fill the formula manually up to last cell, So I manually drag down & Right.

When  I record to Macro its have static data with specific Cells,

Finally I need Dynamic VBA for to do this process.

---

```
Sub Macro2()    'Macro2 Macro
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Range("D2").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Process").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Cells.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
    Sheets("Process").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(Sheet3!R[1]C[3]="""","""",Sheet3!R[1]C[3]&""-K"")"
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    'Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:Z1000"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    'Range("A:Z").Select   End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for editing @Scott Craner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the cells you wish to process and run this:

```
Sub Adding_a_K()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range, v
    Set rng = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Selection)

    For Each r In rng
        v = r.Value
        If v <> "" Then
            r.Value = v & "-K"
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow Excellent @Gary's Student . Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Not enough points to add a comment. So making a post...

To keep it simple,

1. You can add a new sheet to the workbook
2. Apply the formula referring to the source sheet `=IF(Sheet1!A1="","",Sheet1!A1&"-K")`
3. Copy and drag across the size of the source dataset.
4. Finally, remove any extra rows/columns that got included beyond the dataset size.

-- EDIT --

**Macro suggestion:**

Please rename the source and output sheet names as required.

```
Sub AppendTextToAllCells()
'
' AppendTextToAllCells Macro
'
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Output").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(Source!RC="""","""",Source!RC&""-K"")"
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah , its actually i tried manually. But i need  macro for this process

Comment: @baskar - Added a macro solution for you to try...

Comment: its working, but source data have non changble data also, so how fix this

Comment: thanks @karthick Ganesan , My source data start from cell D2. if i proceed with this formula. its not match with my condition

Comment: @baskar - Got it. Then the first line should be `Range("D2").Select`. I'll update the code. Thanks for accepting as an answer. I also see @Gary's Student answer is more cleaner and allows in-place update if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Yeah, same thing i try , . but last line formula do by source data only. So i update the formula by @gary's student VBA code... its now working perfectly.  Thanks for your effort. 